# How to combine Alt+Shift+1 into mouse right click

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to combine Alt+Shift+1 to mouse right click with "AutoHotKey" in some online game. I know that `::send !+1` is alt+shift+1 but troubles in right click.

Comment: Are you trying to Right Click when the user presses Alt+Shift+1?  Or are you trying to trigger Alt+Shift+1 AND Right Click using some other key or trigger?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
; Alt+Shift+1
!+1::Click right
```

See also

[Why don't Hotstrings, Send, and Click work in certain games?](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/FAQ.htm#games)

Answer (score -1):

You can use X-Mouse Button Control

X-Mouse Button Control is a free Windows program that lets you re-configure and increases your mouse's capabilities.

Send any keys using the 'simulated keystrokes' editor

https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/xmousebuttoncontrol.htm

I hope this helps.